# Detecting whether a Flask app handles a URL

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I have a case for having a preliminary frontend Flask app before continuing to my main app.

I've implemented it using a "middleware" pattern:

```
class MyMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, main_app, pre_app):
        self.main_app = main_app
        self.pre_app = pre_app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        # check whether pre_app has a rule for this URL
        with self.pre_app.request_context(environ) as ctx:
            if ctx.request.url_rule is None:
                return self.main_app(environ, start_response)

        return self.pre_app(environ, start_response)
```

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this, without creating a context just to check whether the URL is handled by the app? I want to maintain the flexibility of keeping two apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `flask.Flask` `app` has a [`url_map`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.url_map) property - which is a [`werkzeug.routing.Map`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Map).  You *could* just run [`bind_to_environ`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Map.bind_to_environ) and use [the `test` method from `MapAdapter`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/routing/#werkzeug.routing.MapAdapter.test):

```
if self.pre_app.url_map.bind_to_environ(environ).test(environ['PATH_INFO']):
    return self.pre_app(environ, start_response)

return self.main_app(environ, start_response)
```

I don't know that I'd call it "more idiomatic" but it is another way of handling your use case.